# ValueAnimator to animate a large value (long)

Tags: java, android, int

I am trying to animate a large value (over the int max value) using ValueAnimator but it only seems to animate an int (or float, but it looks awful e.g. 1.07E etc.).

Is it possible to animate a long somehow, or maybe convert a float to show it as an int or something?

Comment: sure: use `ValueAnimator#ofObject`

Comment: What on earth are you animating?